# Accordion not collapsing on reload in liferay

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, liferay, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using liferay to build portlets. I'm creating an accordion with default state as "collapsed". When I expand my accordion and logout from the account and re-login, the accordion stays expanded. How to collapse the accordion on every reload?

```
<liferay-ui:panel-container accordion="false" extended="true">  
<liferay-ui:panel title="label.upload.information"
    defaultState="collapsed" persistState="true" id="documentInformations" 
    cssClass="documentInformations">

    <aui:col width="30">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><strong><liferay-ui:message key="label.upload.title" /></strong></td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td><%=title%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong><liferay-ui:message key="label.upload.speciality" /></strong></td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td><%=speciality%></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </aui:col>

</liferay-ui:panel>
```

Comment: Would you try removing persistState="true" or update persistState="false" from tag?

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately!

Comment: crossposted here: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/57827539